# Create a mechanism to host more open-ended questions from the main sites

Tags: feature-request, questions, per-site-meta

There should be a way to shift an open ended question into a meta and link to it from the main site, or at least have it come up in searches there.  Or maybe Stack Exchange is just too inflexible and a new platform is needed.

Take this question on Stack Overflow for example (the specifics of the question aren't important): [What NoSQL...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net); at the time of this post it had 456 up-votes, 228 stars, and a cumulative 138+ up-votes for comments stating that the question should be reopened.

Additionally, the comments are full of people talking about how useful the question is, but it was closed because "...[it] is not a good fit for our Q&A format...".

Obviously it's a question people are interested in, and it would seem that there should be some why that the SE network would support them (chat isn't it). I originally thought meta, but that got me a whole lot of down votes, so clearly that isn't it.

Still, not having something like this makes SE a lot less useful, because these types of closures happen all the time for questions that people are interested in.

Comment: Ok... then back to my last comment: maybe StackExchange is just too inflexible and a new platform is needed.

Comment: That question is great for SurveyMonkey. Which means it definitely doesn't belong on SE

Comment: Also, down voting a question that's a valid question, even if the solution proposed isn't what people think should happen is pretty sophomoric.

Comment: It's a flawed premise sitting on a dubious understanding with offbase assumptions of what is and isn't in scope. Calls into question if it's even a valid question

Comment: @random, SurveyMonkey? You're kidding right?  This is an actual (in this case development) question that people are interested in discussing, but for which up-voting, etc. still makes sense.

Comment: @derGral People are also interested in posting cute pictures of cats, and voting on their favorites and discussing how cute they are.

Comment: @random, how is it a flawed premise? It's simple: people have (in this case development) questions for which there are better and worse answers (up/down votes). Given your usage, I'm pretty sure you don't know what dubious means.  What's off-base about it?

Comment: @Servy, wow, seriously? You're taking a question about databases, which again, there are better and worse answers for it (makes the structure of SO/SE useful), and making it about cat pictures. That's what I mean: sophomoric.

Comment: Users will also upvote with all their bone marrow if you present a question comparing tabs versus spaces. Or spaces vs tabs.

Comment: @derGral You think there aren't better or worse cat pictures?  Have you ever *seen* collections of cat pictures.  They are not all the same.

Comment: @derGral The criteria for a question being appropriate on SE is not, "It's a question that has good and bad answers."  Apparently [the last time I tried to say this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250906/why-arent-stackexchange-and-their-meta-sites-better-integrated?noredirect=1#comment819028_250906) I was being too subtle.

Comment: popularity (ie upvotes, comments etc) does not equal on topic

Comment: @Servy, my point is concerning usefulness of questions, not quality of answers. The example case is one of many that many people clearly find useful, and the structure of SE/SO does support them well...at least until they're closed on a fairly subjective basis.

Comment: @derGral No, the SE model *doesn't* support them very well.  They cause all sorts of problems, and tend to be rather poor at conveying information in a useful manor.  It's why they're considered out of scope.  As has been said, the fact that these types of questions are often popular doesn't change that.

Comment: @SabreTooth, true, it doesn't.  Popularity of a question does.  Up and down votes help direct attention to useful answers.  Thus, the SE/SO paradigm works well for these question that are useful.  Again, useful is also about the site in question: thus, posting cat pictures on a development site would still definitely be off-topic.

Comment: Asked and answered so many times.  Most of those questions are on [meta.se] now.  Go search for "bikeshed".  Keeping these types of questions of SE was a deliberate act made long long ago. There's a software recommendation site around here somewhere on SE, but I don't have a link to it, as I use what is more commonly called "search engines" to locate frameworks etc

Comment: This question is nowhere near being on topic on Software Recommendations (for the same reason that it's not on topic on SO, in fact).

Comment: @Servy, people like you make people hate this:
site:http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow
http://timschreiber.com/2013/10/30/beware-the-stackoverlords/
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2166021

Comment: @derGral If that makes you want to go post your low quality content elsewhere, instead of trying to continue posting/encouraging low quality content being posted here, then that's fantastic.  I wish you the best of luck elsewhere.  I'd much rather participate in a site full of quality, useful content, where a handful of users don't like me, than participate in a site full of crap in which everyone loves me.

Comment: Posts like this simply do not belong on the Stack Exchange network, no matter how useful or popular they are. Stack Exchange is strictly for questions and answers. That's it. Not questions asking for big lists, tool recommendations, discussions, opinions/polls, etc. If these strict quality standards were not upheld, Stack Exchange would be a lot worse for the niche it fills today.

Comment: @Doorknob, interesting that you this is off topic but said this "Post on meta. Then you will a.) Get reasons why this is a bad idea or b.) It will be implemented into the site" in the question referenced by gnat.

Comment: @derGral I was referring to [the Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net) you linked in your post.

Comment: @Servy, that's the point, there's good quality content to be had but the questions are somewhat subjective.  Whatever though, the point is clearly not well received.  So fine, I'm done.

Comment: "Better to have nothing, no matter when, than to accept rubbish."

Comment: [Quora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) will accept questions like that. Sometimes [you even get an answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-fluent-API-in-this-context). Sometimes [a lot of them](https://www.quora.com/Whats-it-like-to-have-a-150-IQ-Is-life-easier).

Answer (score 14):

Meta sites are there to *discuss the site itself*.  They're not just sites for questions on the topic of the main site that happen to be a poor fit for the Q\A platform (i.e. they are discussions).

That question doesn't belong on meta at all, just like it doesn't belong on the main site.